# PHP OOP: Chainable objects?

Tags: php, oop, fluent-interface, chainable

I have tried to find a good introduction on chainable OOP objects in PHP, but without any good result yet.

How can something like this be done?

```
$this->className->add('1','value');
$this->className->type('string');
$this->classname->doStuff();
```

Or even: `$this->className->add('1','value')->type('string')->doStuff();`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The key is to return the object itself within each method:

```
class Foo {
    function add($arg1, $arg2) {
        // …
        return $this;
    }
    function type($arg1) {
        // …
        return $this;
    }
    function doStuff() {
        // …
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Every method, that returns the object itself, can be used as an intermediate in a method chain. See [Wikipedia’s article on *Method chaining*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) for some further details.

Comment: Amazing how easy this was to do. Had no idea. Thanks a lot Gumbo!

Answer (score 11):

just return $this in the add() and type() methods:

```
function add() {
    // other code
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another term for this is the [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: Adding a note: method chaining is but one technique in creating a fluent interface.